# Handle textDomains with zend-framework3 and gettext

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext, zend-framework3, xgettext

We're using ZF3 for a large app with internationalization.
i18n is done with zend-i18n, zend-mvc-i18n, and xgettext cli for extraction / compilation of pot / po / mo files.
For some words like `Contact` which could be a verb or a noun, we've specified a `$textDomain` : `$this->translate('Contact', 'Verb')` or `$this->translate('Contact', 'Noun')`.

Problem is, when we extract those strings, it's all in the same pot file.
Since Zend load translation files by textDomain, it would be better if we could split `pot` files by textDomain, but it seems like xgettext can't do that.

Could someone help us to manage properly textDomains with Zend and gettext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may have the same problem, we ended up creating our own `Gettext` file loader, which properly parses msgctxt and returns a `TextDomain` structured by msgctxt. 

We also created our own `Translator extends Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator` to override `loadMessagesFrom...` functions and properly update the `$this->messages` variable